# Angular bootstrap-ui conflict with angular masonry - how to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building an angularjs-based product catalog that uses [AngularJS Masonry Directive](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry)  and [AngularJS UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I ran into a problem: **my masonry grid doesn't react to the collapse/expand of an element**, which leads to elements overlapping.

I made this Plunker to illustrate my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/92qJTMlCOTavc6QgtSLb?p=preview

This plunker is a direct translation of my code, as such, it yields the same undesired results.

***Expected result:***

- On expand, the elements below it should move down to accommodate the new element height.

***Actual result:***

- Elements right below don't react to changes and overlap the expanded element.

Comment: This was a while ago, did you find a solution? I imagine I'd go about solving this issue by either raising events and responding to height changes maybe by using angular's change:someProperty databinding to react to the property changes.

Comment: I did solve it but ended up dropping masonry. Wen't with a 3 column layout instead. The solution you hinted at seems like a good way to solve this issue indeed.